# Azure AD - Get User Role - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Question, as I have a complete script that scraps info of users from Azure AD.

However, one thing that I am having trouble with is to get "User Role of any user"

The goal is to check if the logged in user is "Global Administrator", if not, then Exit the script.

```
Write-Host "Connect to AzureAD" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Connect-AzureAD

    Write-Host "[] Validating Azure signed-in User's Role ... " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    $currentUser = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId (Get-AzureADCurrentSessionInfo).Account.Id)    
    $currentUser
    
    $MyName = $currentUser.DisplayName
    Write-Host "[✔] Welcome: $MyName" -ForegroundColor Green
    
    
    
    Write-Host "Your role is: "
```

Tried to use the following two below, with no luck

**Get-AzureADCurrentSessionInfo**

**[Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0)**

Can someone help with that please.

For ref: Screenshot from the GUI

[image: Azure Role GUI]

As there is this script that can be used and integrated with my goal above

```
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Global Administrator'}
Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it.

Here is the script.

```
Connect-AzureAD

#Validate Logged in User's Role (Still in progress, maybe I can use if-else if the user is not Globale Administrator or Application Administrator

Write-Host "[] Validating Azure signed-in User's Role ... " -ForegroundColor Yellow

$currentUser = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId (Get-AzureADCurrentSessionInfo).Account.Id)

$currentUser

$MyName = $currentUser.DisplayName
Write-Host "[✔] Welcome: $MyName" -ForegroundColor Green


Get-AzureADCurrentSessionInfo

Get-AzureADDirectoryRole

#Getting SMTP - UPN Only
$MyNameUPN = $currentUser.UserPrincipalName
$MyNameUPN

#List all Who are Global Admin
$role = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq 'Global Administrator'}
Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId 

#Looking using current user UPN to look for user role under the Global Admins
$UserRole = Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq $MyNameUPN}
$UserRole


#Getting SMTP - UPN Only
$MyNameRoleUPN = $UserRole.UserPrincipalName
$MyNameRoleUPN



#Checker if 

If ($MyNameUPN -eq $MyNameRoleUPN) { 

Write-Host "User is Global Admin!" -ForegroundColor Green 

} Else {

Write-Host "You are not a Global Admin. Sorry! Closing this app" -ForegroundColor Red 

# Pop-up message
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("

 [❌]
 
 Config File
 
You are not a Global Admin.Sorry!

Closing this app❗
 
 ")

 Sleep 1

}
```